# Installing ruby executables via bundler puts them in a different location than gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Having some issues installing a gemset in ruby 1.8.7p334 (enterprise edition) running rails 1.2.6 on Fedora 8.

The main issue I have is that bundler installs the executables in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin`.  However, Gem installs the executables in `/usr/bin`, which is where I want them.

How can I tell bundler to place them in `/usr/bin`?  I've looked at the `--binstubs` flag, but it doesn't seem to complete the necessary requirements.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: just in case you did not know, when installing gems through Bundler, then you usually have to execute their executables through `bundle exec ...`, for example `bundle exec rspec spec/`

Comment: Any idea why they can't be/shouldn't be called directly?

Comment: If you have multiple versions of a gem installed, executing the bin directly will usually load the most recent version instead of the version defined in Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I find the answer after posting the question.  It's the little-documented BUNDLE_BIN configuration key.  It can be set by .bundle/config, an environment variable (my choice) or by bundle config.  Looks like you can also specify it on the command line as --bin.

```
$ export BUNDLE_BIN="/usr/bin"
```

> bin (BUNDLE_BIN)
>       Install executables from gems in the bundle to the specified directory.
>   Defaults to false.